# Locate characers in an image file- Java

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr

Is it possible to locate text in an image. I am looking for an easy to use and fast java library that tells me if my images mostly contain text or not. I don't really care about the content of text so a text detection(not recognition) library/algorithm will do.

I have had a look at Tess4J, Axet, Aspire and Java OCR but they were either platform dependent or too slow.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Arash

Comment: Searching Google shows several good academic papers on the topic, but no specialized tool for just locating text within an image. You could write one up yourself (thought that would likely be a big effort), or adapt the relevant part of an OCR tool, as you already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image to a smaller one, without antialiasing (BufferedImage) and do your own checking: black&white, recognizing lines by avertical column.

What else, unfortunately?

Comment: I converted the image to Black and white using Otsu's method for thresholding with the hope of getting object/background pixels ratio to a certain range for images that have mostly text but that didn't work very well. Any suggestion on recognizing lines? @JoopEggen

Comment: A scammed text page has a regular pattern vertically with more white between the lines. For slightly skewed, angled scans, a narrow vertical column can be scanned.